# changing the style of an input element's parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i wanna change the parent's style of an input element, when its checked

```
<div>  <!--- this is the parent element ---> 
  <input type="radio" data-dynamic-update="1" name="virtuemart_paymentmethod_id" id="payment_id_3" value="3" checked="checked">
</div>
```

i found this after googling:

```
var x = document.getElementById("payment_id_3");
x.addEventListener("click", function(){
    $(x).parent().css({"background-color": "green", "border": "1px solid green"});
});
```

but it doesn't work.. how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution updated with 'change' event and "on document ready" event: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/45tb5rn5/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#payment_id_3').on('change',function(){
    if (this.checked) { //Checked CSS
      $('#payment_id_3').parent().css({
        'background-color': 'green',
        'border': '1px solid green'
      });
     } else { // unchecked CSS
       $('#payment_id_3').parent().css({
         'background-color': 'red',
         'border': '1px solid black'
       });
     }
  });
  $('#payment_id_3').trigger('change');
});
```

NOTICE: I've changed the "radio" to a checkbox.
Edit: Updated JSFiddle link and Code

Comment: thanks. it worked.. what about "onload" instead of "click"

Comment: You can change the click with an `.on('change', `and use a trigger to fire any event `$('#payment_id_3').trigger('change');`
See an working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/45tb5rn5/1/)

Answer (score 1):

this is how you can do it. this example code show you how to use multiple radio buttons and change the style of the parent `div`.

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<title></title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>

#parent{
      width: 100px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: orange;
}

</style>

<body>

<div id="parent">
      <input type="radio" id="green" name="color"> Green<br>
      <input type="radio" id="pink" name="color"> Pink<br>
      <input type="radio" id="purple" name="color"> Purple<br>
      <input type="radio" id="red" name="color"> Red
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

$("#parent input[type=radio]").on('click',function(){
      var theId = $(this).attr('id');

      if (theId =="green") 
      {
            $("#parent").css({"background-color":"green"});
      }
      else if (theId == "pink") 
      {
            $("#parent").css({"background-color":"pink"});
      }
      else if (theId == "purple") 
      {
            $("#parent").css({"background-color":"purple"});
      }
      else
      {
            $("#parent").css({"background-color":"red"});
      }

})

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Note : above is an exapmle to get you an idea of how to do it. change the styles as you need.**

> In your case it can do  with this simple lines.

```
$("#payment_id_3").click(function(){
      $(this).parent().css({"background-color":"green","border": "1px solid green"});
});
```

**note : in your case you should have define some styles to your parent div at the intial stage such as width, heigh. assuming that you have done it.**

Answer (score 0):

Get the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/45tb5rn5/

The problem was with getting the element object:

```
$('#payment_id_3').click(function(){
    $('#payment_id_3').parent().css({"background-color": "green", "border": "1px solid green"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just use jQuery for all instead like so:

```
var x = $("#payment_id_3");
x.click(function(){
    $(this).parent().css({"background-color": "green", "border": "1px solid green"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery then try this:

```
$('#payment_id_3').on("change", function(){
    $(this).parent().css({"background-color": "green", "border": "1px solid green"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a way you can change the div if the checkbox is checked.

```
$('#payment_id_3').click(function(){      
  if($(this).prop('checked')){ // if checked
    $(this).parents('div').css('background-color','red');
  }
  else{ // if not checked
    $(this).parents('div').css('background-color','teal');
  }  
})
```

Here you can check out the [Example](http://jsbin.com/xigiye/edit?html,js,output) in action.